# Why should academic institutions not post timestamps of all assignments on cryptocurrency blockchains?

Tags: technology, information-technology

The best way to prove that a file F existed before time t and has not been altered since then would be to post the cryptographic hash h=H(F) of the file F on the Bitcoin blockchain. When the cryptographic hash h=H(F) of the file F has been posted on a blockchain, we say that the file F has been *timestamped*. Since the cryptographic hash h cannot be changed without altering the file F, and since it will be exceedingly difficult to change the block containing h on the Bitcoin blockchain after time t, one should consider the hash h posted on the Bitcoin blockchain as a proof that the file F existed before time t and has not been altered after time t.

Should academic institutions require faculty to post timestamps of all their students assignments on blockchains? My idea is for the academic institution to require faculty to post a timestamp of each assignment as soon as the assignment is turned in and also after the assignment has been graded. Timestamps are useful for promoting academic integrity. If posting timestamps for every assignment is too rigorous, then should academic institutions require faculty to post timestamps in a more limited context such as for finals, theses, or exit exams only?

I personally think that posting timestamps is a good idea, but there may be some unforeseen consequences to this proposal, so I am looking for reasons why academic institution should not require timestamps of assignments to be posted on blockchains.

**Advantages of secure timestamps:**

1. Timestamps are private. The timestamp h by itself gives no information about the file F being timestamped.
2. Timestamps are inexpensive. The transaction fee for posting something on the Bitcoin blockchain is currently between 2 and 3 dollars. However, it is just as effective to post the timestamps on some other blockchain like the Litecoin blockchain with lower transaction fees since the hash of the Litecoin blockchain will be periodically posted on the Bitcoin blockchain. One can reduce the fees much further by bundling many timestamps together into one transaction using Merkle roots. By using Merkle roots this way, one can post an arbitrary amount of timestamps on the blockchain using only one transaction without compromising the privacy of the data being timestamped. The cost of posting timestamps on blockchains should therefore be negligible.
3. Timestamps are censorship resistant. Since people will not be able to know the information being timestamped in the first place, it is not possible for people to censor the information being timestamped in any way.

**Why secure timestamps are needed for assignments:**

Timestamping assignments will create an immutable paper trail that will make it easier for instructors to maintain academic integrity without giving into the students' demands. Consider the following scenarios:

1. Suppose that students are given an examination, but at the end of class certain students beg for extra time and are quite adamant about needing extra time. If the assignments were not timestamped after being turned in, then the instructor would be more likely to give in and give the few students extra time. If the assignments were timestamped on a blockchain, then the instructor would not be able to give certain students extra time without creating verifiable a paper trail. Similarly, if students ask for an extension for an assignment that is already past due, then such an extension could not be given without creating a timestamped paper trail.
2. Suppose that a student asks to have a grade for an assignment changed. If the assignment was graded incorrectly, then the grader can change the grade and submit a new timestamp that has a memo stating that the grade was changed as well as the reason why the grade was changed. The same protocol applies in case the task was poorly worded or something that the students did not cover in class. On the other hand, if the assignment was graded correctly but the student simply wants points for an incorrect answer (or more partial credit), then it would be hard to write a timestamped memo that justifies the grade change.
3. Suppose that some students obtain a copy of the examination before the examination was given. Then students could themselves post a timestamp of this examination before it is given, and this timestamp will prove that students have obtained a copy of the examination early.

There are other scenarios in which secure timestamps would be helpful for ensuring honesty and fairness for everyone. It therefore seems as if timestamping assignments will be a simple solution (though not a perfect solution) for several of these issues.

**Possible pitfalls:**

Here are a few reasons why it may be a bad idea to post timestamps of assignments on blockchains, but these reasons are unconvincing to me.

1. Hacks could compromise student's privacy. This is a problem, but I am not convinced that this problem is bad enough for the institutions to abandon the practice of posting timestamps on blockchains. A better solution would be to simply have better cybersecurity.
2. Posting the timestamps on blockchains will take a little bit of work. I think it is worth the small amount of work in order to help maintain academic integrity.
3. Institutions may think that they already have enough academic integrity and that this proposal is unnecessary. I am not convinced that this is the case.

Comment: Academia.SE is a good place to get specific answers to specific questions about academia; it's not a great place to rant or promote some idea you have. I question whether you have much understanding of what "academic integrity" issue it is you are trying to solve.

Comment: @BryanKrause. My intention was not to promote any idea but to investigate the idea to see if it should be used in practice since there may be unintended consequences to posting timestamps on blockchains. In any case, I was not sure if this question would be closed or not.

Comment: What problem is this meant to solve? It seems extremely pointless to me.

Comment: If there are timestamped records of all assignments, then faculty would be much less likely to inflate the grades, and students would be much less likely to cheat. Furthermore, faculty will be much less likely to alter the grades after the assignment has been graded because the student complained or has gotten really belligerent because any alteration to the grades will be documented. I am pretty sure that faculty members do not want to deal with belligerent students asking for the grades to be changed either since that ruins morale.

Comment: "Grade inflation" is about the trend to make assignments/tests/courses more easily passable; it has nothing to do with modifying grades after the fact. Sometimes, grades on assignments *do* need to be changed because they are *incorrect grades*; other times, students complain about grades given correctly. A timestamp doesn't help you tell between those circumstances.

Comment: This seems like _extreme_ overkill. Mostly we depend on trust. It isn't like a pension system.

Comment: The case where students complain about incorrect grades is not a problem. This only requires for faculty members to post a new timestamp in order to overwrite the old grade. In any case, there should be a record of this correction.

Comment: If there is a record of the assignments, then institutions and faculty members will be much less likely to get away with inflating the grades. Timestamps will also make it much less likely for professors to give certain students favors over other students if they want to turn an assignment in late.

Comment: Grade inflation is not something institutions and faculty members "get away with". You completely misunderstand the problem you claim to solve.

Comment: @BryanKrause. I really do not understand the argument that you are attempting to make. I would appreciate it if you would give a detailed answer explaining what you mean?

Comment: Grade inflation is a systemic issue; the problem is that if other institutions and courses consider an "A" grade to mean "this student adequately understands the material", instructors and universities are pressured to match this standard. Even if they would like a "C" grade to mean "this student adequately understands the material" and an "A" grade to mean "this is the best student I've ever seen", they cannot do so without fearing that students in their class/institution who get a "C" grade will be incorrectly judged by everyone else's criteria rather than the one they actually applied...

Comment: ...it's a pressure to not raise standards for a certain grade. It does not mean to fudge individual grades. Grade inflation happens by making assignments easier, by assigning grades of A and B to work that is satisfactory rather than outstanding. It's about labels.

Comment: What would be the point of a time stamp?  Generally the assignments have been moderated before they are released to the students (i.e. by someone other than the marker), and once they are on the system they can't be directly changed by faculty.  I am assuming my institution is not unusual in this respect.  Students being able to prove what they wrote and when (if they fail to submit it correctly), that would be far more useful (but we already have solutions for that).

Comment: How would a timestamp discourage students from cheating?

Comment: Um. There are many ways to cheat, and timestamps discourage some methods of cheating. For example, if one student takes an examination late because he wants to obtain a copy of the examination before taking it, then people who have access to the timestamped files can see that the student who takes the examination late is taking the exact same examination as everyone else.

Comment: "Students being able to prove what they wrote and when (if they fail to submit it correctly), that would be far more useful (but we already have solutions for that)."-For this you need blockchains as well.

Comment: Well you shouldn't allow the student to hand in their exercise late...

Comment: I would rather not enforce the "no late assignments" policies myself since that would put me in an adversarial position against the students. It will be better if this "no late assignments" policy were enforced by the computers.

Comment: Sure, the exercise is closed when the time is up. No need for additional technology.

Comment: And what if the exercise gets reopened again? What if the exercise is turned in in person at the end of class rather than online? What if a few students beg for additional time at the end of class to complete the examination? Timestamps will prevent students from begging for extra time or asking for an assignment to be reopened again since a timestamped paper trail will be created in each of these scenarios.

Comment: "Timestamps will prevent students from begging for extra time or asking for an assignment to be reopened again" - this seems incredibly naïve, and in any event it's up to the instructor anyways what to accept and **should be**. You also have cases of disability accommodations - should such students be identifiable by having timestamps later than others? Frankly, your comments at this point seem indistinguishable from trolling. If you're a true believer in blockchain I'd really recommend taking a step back because you're probably doing more damage than good to the potential use of the tech.

Comment: *What if the exercise is turned in in person at the end of class rather than online?* How do you hash a stack of paper?

Comment: This looks like a solution in search of a problem. If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. There are tried and tested conventional solutions for all the scenarios you mention. Blockchain(TM) doesn't make everything better. Salted caramel, sure; baby kittens, perhaps; but not blockchain.

Comment: "You also have cases of disability accommodations - should such students be identifiable by having timestamps later than others?"-They can start or take the examination early. "How do you hash a stack of paper?"-You use a scanner.

Comment: @JosephVanName releasing assessments to some students early creates a significantly bigger risk of academic misconduct than any timestamp could prevent, especially if the assessment itself is electronic.

Comment: @origimbo. Please elaborate.

Comment: I want to thank everyone here for convincing me that we need to make academic assignments auditable by posting the timestamps on the blockchain and having some record of the assignment. I know that was not anyone's intention, but the people here have been really convincing.

Answer (score 7):

There is existing software (e.g. moodle, gradescope, etc) that can handle timestamps without making people setup a bitcoin wallet, buy bitcoin, and make non-standard transactions ('posting').

Comment: If done correctly, a user should be able to submit a timestamp to the Bitcoin blockchain for free without setting up a wallet, buying Bitcoin, or doing anything complicated or even using energy intensive computations.

Comment: To have any cryptographic security, one needs to post the timestamps on blockchains.

Comment: @JosephVanName I am not sure what you are expecting from us college students. Do you think one of us is going to hack into Gradescope servers and change the timestamps, thereby necessitating a decentralized immutable blockchain to maintain integrity?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to verify that the timestamps cannot be changed without hacking the servers? It is easier to just look at timestamps on the blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the main misunderstanding in this question is the assumption that what the student handed in has to change when the grade changes. Changing the material after it has been handed in would be clear fraud and there is no reason for lecturer to go along with that unless there is real bribery. This is pretty rare, mainly because students are way too poor to offer a bribe big enough to compensate for the risk the lecturer is running.

However, it is quite common for grades to change. There is always a bit of room for interpretation, especially when it comes to partial points. Moreover, the key can be adjusted. I do that when I find out that a substantial portion of students misunderstood the question, so the answers to that question no longer measure what I want to test.

So changing to content after it is handed in is not an issue. We don't need some machinery to prevent us from doing that, because too rare and thus a non problem. It won't prevent fraud, because there plenty of other ways to change the grade. If I were planning fraud (and I am not) I would use those other methods anyhow because they are just easier.

Comment: There are other ways to put pressure on the lecturers to change grades besides monetary bribes. Students could misbehave in class. They could complain to try to get the professor terminated.

Comment: We know, and were are very good at detecting malicious complainers. There are many bureaucratic black holes in which they can disappear. That is not a real thread. If you want better grades, then misbehaving in class or threatening me is not a winning strategy... Remember, members of a department talk to one another.

Comment: The institutions that I have taught at have dealt with malicious complainers against me extremely poorly. For this reason, I will only trust the institution at all if it has a system in place that makes it impossible to change a grade or anything without leaving a paper trail that has been timestamped on the blockchain. Keep in mind that nobody is familiar with the practices at all institutions, so to ensure that people trust such institutions it is best to have a system in place that promotes honesty.

Comment: I am sorry you had such a bad experience. However, I still don't see the problem that your proposal solves. Exercises are never changed after they are handed in, so a block chain "solves" a complete non-issue. I guess the main feedback you got thus far is that you need to do more work on presenting what the advantages are of your solution. I am done with this question.

Comment: "Exercises are never changed after they are handed in"-You will need to use blockchains to back up this statement. And no, I am not going to be convinced by the 'integrity' of the institutions at all. But why make this statement unless someone is keeping records of all assignments in the first place?

Comment: "misbehaving in class or threatening me is not a winning strategy"-So does this mean that students all behave well in class now? Does this mean that colleges know how to handle malicious students properly?

Comment: I am not making any claims about the integrity of the institutions. All I am saying is that it is much easier and safer for a dishonest teacher to change the grade without changing what the student handed in. I am not saying that all teachers are honest, all I am saying is that even dishonest teachers won't change the exercise, because there is an easier way to commit fraud... I know you are really really really really fond of blockchains, but it is not the solution here.

Comment: "So does this mean that students all behave well in class now? Does this mean that colleges know how to handle malicious students properly?" I did not say that. If you are really interested in what I had to say you can read my comment again.

Comment: I am only in favor of using blockchains when there is a chance that blockchains can be used to solve important problems. Since dishonest teachers may simply give students points for no reason at all or they discriminate in favor of some students (which is why we need double blind grading for most assignments as well as timestamps), there needs to be a record of the completed assignments and grades so that such dishonesty does not go unnoticed and so that nobody can cover up such dishonesty.

Comment: Ok. Let me read your statement again. "We know, and were are very good at detecting malicious complainers."-And from my experience, these institutions cannot deal with malicious complainers and hostile students properly. It does not make sense to talk to about whether hostility is a winning strategy since not all students are rational, and college tend to be irrational as well (at least in my experience).

Comment: If you want to move forwards with this, then the take-away message from this discussion is that your presentation has not convinced this audience. Shouting harder and calling people dishonest, is not going to work. So you need something else.

Comment: I would try to convince one institution, or probably one department within an institution to start a pilot project. You need to be very specific about the exact problem you solve and how your method will solve that. Once the pilot study is a success (document the criteria for declaring a success before the pilot on a blockchain!), you will have an easier time to find supporters. Right now, you are not getting anywhere.

Comment: A pilot project is a good idea. "Right now, you are not getting anywhere."-My goal was not to convince people of anything; I simply wanted to know what others think about timestamping assignments.

Comment: "I simply wanted to know what others think about timestamping assignments." This is the wrong forum for that purpose. This is why your question was closed. We are here to help people find their way in academia. I think that is where most of the misunderstandings in the comments came from: People were trying to coach you into turning your proposal into something workable and you did not want to be coached or expected to be coached.

Comment: "This is why your question was closed. . . . People were trying to coach you into turning your proposal into something workable and you did not want to be coached or expected to be coached."-This is not true at all. I was looking for **actual reasons** 
(with justification) why it may not be a good idea to timestamp assignments, and I did not find any that are satisfactory here. It is certainly not good to leave a bad impression even if that was not anyone's intentions.

Comment: Let's just say that our perceptions of the exchanges in this thread differ fundamentally.